# Choose items from an array, each from a different row and column

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Thirty items are arranged in a 6-by-5 array. Calculate the number of ways to form a set of three distinct items such that no two of the selected items are in the same row or same column.

The answer key gives 1200, but I get 7200. My thought process is as such: 
Choose 1 item, which eliminates itself and its column/rowmates from the pool, leaving 20. Choose another, leaving 12. Choose the last item. My formula for this is

$_{30}C{_1}\cdot_{20}C{_1}\cdot_{12}C_1 = 30\cdot20\cdot12 = 7200$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  There is a reasonable attempt to solve the problem, allowing a precise answer to what is wrong.

Comment: The first thing you're doing wrong is the title of this question. Can you give it a title that doesn't require me to open the question to know *what* sort of question this is? (The only thing the current title tells me is that I need to come here and make this comment.)

Comment: My apologies. It's my first day using the site, and the title portion automatically filled with my last search query (in trying to find if the question had already been asked). Since the question was already answered by the time I noticed, I didn't bother changing it.

Comment: See, the thing is that this question is not just for you. It's also for future visitors, who might have similar questions, or perhaps have different answers to give. Wouldn't it be nice if they could find your question more easily? We don't edit stuff for the sake of the original poster, we edit stuff for future visitors.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Again, my apologies. I have updated the title. Please take a look at it and let me know if you have any more constructive criticism.

Comment: Yeah, that's much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an attempt to avoid a "division by symmetry" argument (*or at least disguise such an argument with binomial coefficients*) you can do the following:

- Simultaneously choose the three columns used ($\binom{5}{3}$ options)
- Simultaneously choose the three rows used ($\binom{6}{3}$ options)
- Pick which row from those chosen is partnered with the left-most selected column ($3$ options)
- Pick which row from those remaining chosen is partnered with the left-most remaining selected column ($2$ options)
- The final selected row is partnered then with the final remaining selected column ($1$ option)

This gives a final total as $\binom{5}{3}\cdot \binom{6}{3}\cdot 3\cdot 2 = 1200$

Comment: Sweet. If I were to extend this to a 5x5x5 cube, would the following work?

Choose three x-axis points simultaneously (5 choose 3)  
Choose three y-axis points simultaneously (5 choose 3)  
Choose three z-axis points simultaneously (5 choose 3)  
Group first x point to a y and z point (3*3 options)  
Group next x point to a remaining y and z point (2*2 options)  
Group remaining points together (1 option)

Comment: Yes &~~~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 2):

You are counting the $3!=6$ orders to choose the three items separately.  The question only wants the combinations of three items.  I think your approach is a good one, but you need to divide by $3!$ at the endj.

Comment: So by using combinations, I thought I was being "orderless," but by multiplying the results of each combination together, I was effectively "adding order" back into the problem?

Comment: @T.Biscuit  You could have chosen the same three positions in the array for the items in $3!$ orders.  Suppose you place item A at $(1, 2)$, then place item B at $(3, 4)$, and then place item C at $(6, 5)$.  You obtain the same arrangement if you place item C at $(6, 5)$, then place item A at $(1, 2)$, and then place item $B$ at $(3, 4)$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig and it's 3! orders because there are 3 items, right?

Comment: @T.Biscuit:  that is correct